# C++ reversing char* adds "a"

Tags: c++

I have a HUGE problem, I am printing in console reverse arguments, for example "./program.exe foo bar sula" would output "oof rab alus", but for some reason it adds "a" before every word "aoof arab aalus", can anyone help with this?
Here's my code.

```
for(int i=1;i<argc;i++){
    for(int j=strlen(argv[i]);j>-1;j--){
        cout<<argv[i][j];
    }
    cout<<" ";
}
```

Comment: the range is ]strlen,0], not [strlen,0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last **legal** index of an array is `size-1`.

For example: in the array `[0,1,2,3,4]` with the length of 5, the last legal index is: 4.

Meaning, when you start printing the string from `index = strlen(...)`, you're out of bound.
you should change your second loop to run from `strlen(argv[i])-1`:

```
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    for(int j=strlen(argv[i])-1; j>-1; j--) {
        cout << argv[i][j];
    }
    cout << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = strlen( argv[i] ); j != 0; j-- )
    {
        cout << argv[i][j-1];
    }
    cout<<" ";
}
```

Standard C function `strlen` has return type `size_t`. So it is better to use a variable used as the index of that type that is of type `size_t`

If a string is empty then `strlen` will return 0. So the most readable condition of the inner loop is

```
j != 0
```

that is do the loop if the string is not empty.  The string length can not be negative.:)

Comment: Could you give me some kind of program to make for a beginner, I find that it's the best way to learn.

Comment: @DatKaspars You can try to do the assignments that are described in questions of other beginners in this forum.

Comment: @DatKaspars  The more you know the better.:)

Answer (score -1):

Why is it like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<argc;i++){
```

I think it should be like this, if you want to loop all commands:

```
for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
```

Comment: No. The `0th` argument is the program name. First argument is on index `1`.

Comment: argc=0 will be program name ("program.exe").